# How to wrap a (**) type in a C++\CLI wrapper

Tags: .net, c++-cli, wrapper, mixed-mode

I need to write a C++\CLI wrapper. My main goal is to process some pixel data that is being provide in my .NET code. The algorithm is written in C++.

I have the `dll` and the header of the C++ code and I need to write a wrapper in order to use the API in C#.

**The C++ header**

```
int Func1(unsigned short const* const* inputImage, int const* size, double const* res) ;
```

I'm not sure how to wrap this type of method. The given `inputImage` is actually a pointer to multiple concatenated images pixel data.

**my wrapper.h**

```
int Func1Wrapper(unsigned short const* const* inputImage, int const size, double const res);
```

**my wrapper.cpp**

```
int MyWrapper::Func1Wrapper(unsigned short const* const* inputImage,
    int const size, double const res){
        return Func1(inputImage, &size, &res);
}
```

As you can see, I replaced `int const* size` with `int const size` in the wrapper and I pass `&size`. Is this correct?

How should I wrap the `unsigned short const* const* inputImage`? I understand I have to replace this type with some other type in order to make it easy to use on the C# side.

Also, which type will be used in the C# code?

```
__type?__ inputImage;
int size = 512;
double res = 0;
myWrapperInstance.Func1Wrapper(inputImage, size, res);
```

---

### C++ usage example

```
//The image data I need to initialize
struct imageData
{
    int sizes[3];
    double scales[3];
    double origin[3];
    short* buffer; // my Func1Wrapper will initialize this field
    unsigned short ** bufferSlices; // or this directly
};

// my data won't come from a file, but will be given to me as an inner image object, 
// so I will be filling the imageData struct on my own.
// In my question I'm trying to fill the imageslices or buffer - doesnt matter
void read_data(const char* filename, imageData& image){
    ImageReaderHandle reader_handler = MedisysImageReaders_Create(filename);
    int bufferSize = image.sizes[0] * image.sizes[1] * image.sizes[2];
    image.buffer = new short[bufferSize];
    MedisysImageReaders_ReadData(reader_handler, image.buffer, bufferSize);

    // MedisysImageReader outputs a short*, for this example, will be casted     into unsigned short without complete carless!
    image.bufferSlices = new unsigned short*[image.sizes[2]];
    int xySize = image.sizes[0] * image.sizes[1];
    for (int z = 0; z < image.sizes[2]; z++) image.bufferSlices[z] = (unsigned short*)(image.buffer + z*xySize);
}
```

Comment: Do you need your C# API to be CLS compliant?

Comment: @toadflakz no, I don't

Comment: The basic idea of *wrapping* is that you expose a type or function in a friendlier way so it is easy to use in a target language like C#.  Just blindly repeating unsigned short const* const* is not wrapping and not friendly, passing the buck to the C# programmer to cough up the the required arguments doesn't solve anything.  You have to know what the native function does first.  Hard to imagine, judging from the argument names alone, that the wrapper's argument should be anything more than a System::Drawing::Bitmap^.  Use its LockBits() method to force the pixel format and generate the pointer

Comment: @HansPassant I know, this is what the question is all about. I don't know how to make this conversion. I added the current code, to show what I did so far and to make it easier to understand what I need to convert.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you mean, you don't know how to use LockBits?  If you want an accurate answer instead of a guess then you have to post sample C or C++ code that shows the function being used so we can infer what kind of data it needs.  If you don't have any sample code then contact the author of the function and ask for some.

Comment: I edited my question. The `inputImage` is a pointer to multiple concatenated images pixel data. I also added a short c++ usage example.

Answer (score 3):

Part 1 is fairly easy.

In C++, `int const*` is a read-only pointer to an integer. You can have read-only pointers to non-constant integers. That just means you can't write through that pointer, but you can still change the pointed-to integer in other ways. Hence, your wrapper doesn't need the const in `int const size`.

However, `int const*` can point to the *first integer of an array*. This is a semantic convention, you don't know how many integers there are in the array. More worryingly, in this case there's a `double const* res` following the parameter named `size`. It is quite possible that `res` points to an array of `size` doubles. Check the documentation.

For part 2, you pretty much know that an image will be an array. You might pass a `unsigned short const* inputImage` in the wrapper, and then pass `&inputImage`
to the underlying function. You'll need to pin the array in C++/CLI to get a `unsigned short const*`.

Comment: The C# interface for this method will thus have the `inputImage` parameter as type `UIntPtr` as the type to map to `unsigned short const*` afaik. This is not CLS-compliant but the OP has said this is not necessary.

Comment: @MSalters, in that case, which type should I use in the C# code? (I added this to my question as well)